# Tee doesn't get the output from the pipe

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to output to a file through Tee,But it isn't working. Surprisingly it used to work before, But now it doesn't. Please tel me the problem or help me with an alternative code.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
dirname=/path
exec > path/logfile.log 2>&1
tempfile=myTempfileName
find $dirname -type f  > $tempfile
cat $tempfile | sed 's_.*/__' | sort |  uniq -d |
while read fileName
do
 grep "$fileName" $tempfile
done
} | tee 'path/scripts/tj_var1.txt'
#| awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  | tee 'path/scripts/tj_var1.txt' | sort -u | tee 'path/scripts/tj_mail1.txt'
```

The log shows the output is being generated. But somehow the it doesn't pass on to tee command output. i could see tee is trying to write something, by the time stamp of the file. But there is nothing in the file.

[image]

Comment: Read about buffering. Buffering in pipes and line buffering.

Comment: @KamilCuk - yes, i did read. its a little confusing! could you fix the tee command in the above code, i'd much appreciate it

Comment: Is the input interactive or endless? Or the script is one shot job that should execute and end? `sed 's_.*/__'` - use `find ... -print '%f\n'`. `while read fileName` - use `xargs -d$'\n' grep "$filename"`. Och `exec > path/logfile.log` - why do you redirect the output to logfile.log if you want to output to pipe?

Comment: It is a bash script, there is no interaction from user. It basically finds out the duplicate filenames and outputs it.

Comment: What is going on with `grep "$fileName" "$tempfile"`? You get the names from a file, and then check if the names are in the same file you get it from? It's like doing `a=$(head -n1 file); grep "$a" file` - well, you got the line from the file, so it's going to be there because it's from there.

Comment: "$fileName" "$tempfile" yes, check the names in the same file i get it from

Comment: `check the names in the same file i get it from ` - well, the names are going to be there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect the output to `exec > path/logfile.log` then... well, the output will be redirected to the file, not to the pipe.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
   dirname=/path
   tempfile=myTempfileName
   find "$dirname" -type f > "$tempfile"
   sed 's_.*/__' "$tempfile" | sort | uniq -d |
   while read fileName
   do
      grep "$fileName" "$tempfile"
   done
} 2>&1 | tee -a path/logfile.log | tee 'path/scripts/tj_var1.txt'
#            ^^ I guess log file should be appended.
```

I guess you could have only stdout in the `tj_var1.txt` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
{
   dirname=/path
   tempfile=myTempfileName
   find "$dirname" -type f > "$tempfile"
   sed 's_.*/__' "$tempfile" | sort | uniq -d |
   while read fileName
   do
      grep "$fileName" "$tempfile"
   done
} | tee 'path/scripts/tj_var1.txt'
} 2>&1 | tee -a path/logfile.log
```

> It basically finds out the duplicate filenames and outputs it.

Just:

```
dirname=/path
find "$dirname" -type f -printf "%f\n" |
sort | uniq -d |
tee -a path/logfile.log | tee 'path/scripts/tj_var1.txt'
```

Comment: So, do i tried just the last part..

dirname=/path
find "$dirname" -type f -print "%f\n" |
sort | uniq -d |
tee -a path/logfile.log | tee 'path/scripts/tj_var1.txt

it is giving some  error - unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Comment: So add the trailing `'` that is missing. Don't you see it?

Comment: yes, sorry, my bad! ive barely slept! Now it says
error - find:paths must precede expression:%f\n

Comment: you mean find "$dirname" -type f printf "%f\n" 

error is stil the same

Comment: `-type f printf "%f\n"` -> `-type f -printf "%f\n"`

Comment: Ahhh, Finallyyy!!! Thank you soo much @KamilCuk why do u think tee and that entire code worked for me before and not now ?